# How do I apply multiple layouts in Codename One?

Tags: java, layout, codenameone

I have been trying to customize the business theme in Codename One. So far I have added extra buttons. Right now I am trying to get those buttons to be constrained by a y- axis boxlayout, but I am currently getting a `IllegalArgumentException`. I have set the form to a border layout:

```
Form hi = new Form("Welcome", new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER_ABSOLUTE));
Button Customer = new Button("Customer");
Button gpsProduct = new Button("Find A product Near You");
Button learnMore = new Button("Learn More");
Button Website = new Button("Visit Our Website");
hi.add(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS, Customer).
   add(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS, learnMore).
   add(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS, gpsProduct).
   add(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS, Website);
hi.show();
```

Comment: Whenever you have an exception, always post the COMPLETE stack trace in your question, and identify the statement in your code that throws the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Box layout Y isn't a constraint for border layout. It's unclear how you wanted this to look but I'm guessing you want something like this which will arrange the components one after the other:

```
Form hi = new Form("Welcome", BoxLayout.y());
Button Customer = new Button("Customer");
Button gpsProduct = new Button("Find A product Near You");
Button learnMore = new Button("Learn More");
Button Website = new Button("Visit Our Website");
hi.add(Customer).
   add(learnMore).
   add(gpsProduct).
   add(Website);
hi.show();
```

Here are two nested examples that place the box in a border layout parent:

```
Form hi = new Form("Welcome", new BorderLayout());
Button Customer = new Button("Customer");
Button gpsProduct = new Button("Find A product Near You");
Button learnMore = new Button("Learn More");
Button Website = new Button("Visit Our Website");
Container box = new Container(BoxLayout.y());
box.add(Customer).
   add(learnMore).
   add(gpsProduct).
   add(Website);
hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, box);
hi.show();
```

This can be written in shorthand as:

```
Form hi = new Form("Welcome", new BorderLayout());
Button Customer = new Button("Customer");
Button gpsProduct = new Button("Find A product Near You");
Button learnMore = new Button("Learn More");
Button Website = new Button("Visit Our Website");
hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, 
      BoxLayout.encloseY(Customer, learnMore, gpsProduct, Website););
hi.show();
```

Comment: Yes, I want the buttons to be one after the other, however I didn't want the entire form to be that way. I was attempting to have my buttons in a boxlayout and everything else in a border layout (I am adding more components). I tried doing this with the theme res editor, however I could not achieve what I wanted, so I turned to hand coding this. I used the theme res to set the background for my form and nothing else.

Comment: Added two more samples of nesting